# Undocumented NSURLErrorDomain error codes (-1001, -1003 and -1004) using StoreKit

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, storekit, nsurlerrordomain

I'm writing StoreKit-related code, and I'm getting some rather troubling error codes when I try to add a purchase to the queue.

So far, I've experienced error codes -1003 and -1004 and I can't find anything about those codes on the internet.

Running a product request returns valid product numbers, so I don't know why calls to `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:aPayment];` would fail with this undocumented problem.

The same code also works without the errors on one device but not on another.

The questions I have are, as of yet, unanswered:

What do these codes mean?
How can I mitigate this problem?
Why are they happening for purchase attempts and not for product requests?

Troubleshooting I've done includes regenerating a signing certificate and provisioning profile, changing WiFi networks, cleaning and building and reinstalling all related software and components, and none of these things individually or together have helped fix the problem.

EDIT:

Found a discussion about this on the Apple dev forums, but no one from Apple has responded: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/107121?tstart=75 (iOS developer account required to view)

EDIT:

I was hit with error code -1001 today, to add to this list of inexplicable and intermittent problems.  Still no accountability from Apple, that I can find.

EDIT:

I have a suspicion that these error codes are randomly generated and really only indicate that the Sandbox is down.  Anyone else experience this problem?

Answer (score 357, accepted):

All error codes are on "CFNetwork Errors Codes References" on the documentation ([link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cfnetwork/cfnetworkerrors))

A small extraction for CFURL and CFURLConnection Errors:

```
  kCFURLErrorUnknown   = -998,
  kCFURLErrorCancelled = -999,
  kCFURLErrorBadURL    = -1000,
  kCFURLErrorTimedOut  = -1001,
  kCFURLErrorUnsupportedURL = -1002,
  kCFURLErrorCannotFindHost = -1003,
  kCFURLErrorCannotConnectToHost    = -1004,
  kCFURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost  = -1005,
  kCFURLErrorDNSLookupFailed        = -1006,
  kCFURLErrorHTTPTooManyRedirects   = -1007,
  kCFURLErrorResourceUnavailable    = -1008,
  kCFURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet = -1009,
  kCFURLErrorRedirectToNonExistentLocation = -1010,
  kCFURLErrorBadServerResponse             = -1011,
  kCFURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication   = -1012,
  kCFURLErrorUserAuthenticationRequired    = -1013,
  kCFURLErrorZeroByteResource        = -1014,
  kCFURLErrorCannotDecodeRawData     = -1015,
  kCFURLErrorCannotDecodeContentData = -1016,
  kCFURLErrorCannotParseResponse     = -1017,
  kCFURLErrorInternationalRoamingOff = -1018,
  kCFURLErrorCallIsActive               = -1019,
  kCFURLErrorDataNotAllowed             = -1020,
  kCFURLErrorRequestBodyStreamExhausted = -1021,
  kCFURLErrorFileDoesNotExist           = -1100,
  kCFURLErrorFileIsDirectory            = -1101,
  kCFURLErrorNoPermissionsToReadFile    = -1102,
  kCFURLErrorDataLengthExceedsMaximum   = -1103,
```

Comment: These are within the CFNetwork framework > CFNetworkErrors.h header.

Comment: These constants don't compile in Swift, but e.g. `NSURLErrorUnknown` does. Any clues?

Comment: Oh, never mind... found the Swift version here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/CFNetworkErrors/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CFNetworkErrors

Answer (score 25):

I have similar problems, in my case seem to be related to network connectivity:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."

Things to check:

- Is there any chance that your server is not able to respond within some time limit? Like 60 seconds or 4 minutes?
- Is there a possibility that your device is switching networks (WiFi, 3G, VPN)?
- Could someone (client vs. server) be waiting for authentication?

Sorry, no ideas how to fix. Just debugging this, trying to find out what the problem is (-1021, -1001, -1009)

**Update:** Google search was very kind to find this:

- -1001    TimedOut - it took longer than the timeout which was alotted.
- -1003    CannotFindHost - the host could not be found.
- -1004    CannotConnectToHost - the host would not let us establish a connection.

Comment: "Is there any chance that your server is not able to respond within some time limit?" You know, that's the killer, it's Apple's server that I'm trying to contact with this code, so it's not my server that's hiccoughing.

Comment: Hey Jom,  In iPhone it is working good for us but in iPad we are getting crash sometimes,  this message shows i.e., "-1001 TimedOut" message. But my question is , If TimedOut it should come in both iPhone and iPad.  Thanks in Advance @JOM

Answer (score 22):

see NSURLError.h Define

```
NSURLErrorUnknown =             -1,
NSURLErrorCancelled =           -999,
NSURLErrorBadURL =              -1000,
NSURLErrorTimedOut =            -1001,
NSURLErrorUnsupportedURL =          -1002,
NSURLErrorCannotFindHost =          -1003,
NSURLErrorCannotConnectToHost =         -1004,
NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost =       -1005,
NSURLErrorDNSLookupFailed =         -1006,
NSURLErrorHTTPTooManyRedirects =        -1007,
NSURLErrorResourceUnavailable =         -1008,
NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet =      -1009,
NSURLErrorRedirectToNonExistentLocation =   -1010,
NSURLErrorBadServerResponse =       -1011,
NSURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication =     -1012,
NSURLErrorUserAuthenticationRequired =  -1013,
NSURLErrorZeroByteResource =        -1014,
NSURLErrorCannotDecodeRawData =             -1015,
NSURLErrorCannotDecodeContentData =         -1016,
NSURLErrorCannotParseResponse =             -1017,
NSURLErrorAppTransportSecurityRequiresSecureConnection NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_11, 9_0) = -1022,
NSURLErrorFileDoesNotExist =        -1100,
NSURLErrorFileIsDirectory =         -1101,
NSURLErrorNoPermissionsToReadFile =     -1102,
NSURLErrorDataLengthExceedsMaximum NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_5, 2_0) =   -1103,

// SSL errors
NSURLErrorSecureConnectionFailed =      -1200,
NSURLErrorServerCertificateHasBadDate =     -1201,
NSURLErrorServerCertificateUntrusted =  -1202,
NSURLErrorServerCertificateHasUnknownRoot = -1203,
NSURLErrorServerCertificateNotYetValid =    -1204,
NSURLErrorClientCertificateRejected =   -1205,
NSURLErrorClientCertificateRequired =   -1206,
NSURLErrorCannotLoadFromNetwork =       -2000,

// Download and file I/O errors
NSURLErrorCannotCreateFile =        -3000,
NSURLErrorCannotOpenFile =          -3001,
NSURLErrorCannotCloseFile =         -3002,
NSURLErrorCannotWriteToFile =       -3003,
NSURLErrorCannotRemoveFile =        -3004,
NSURLErrorCannotMoveFile =          -3005,
NSURLErrorDownloadDecodingFailedMidStream = -3006,
NSURLErrorDownloadDecodingFailedToComplete =-3007,

NSURLErrorInternationalRoamingOff NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_7, 3_0) =         -1018,
NSURLErrorCallIsActive NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_7, 3_0) =                    -1019,
NSURLErrorDataNotAllowed NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_7, 3_0) =                  -1020,
NSURLErrorRequestBodyStreamExhausted NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_7, 3_0) =      -1021,

NSURLErrorBackgroundSessionRequiresSharedContainer NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_10, 8_0) = -995,
NSURLErrorBackgroundSessionInUseByAnotherProcess NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_10, 8_0) = -996,
NSURLErrorBackgroundSessionWasDisconnected NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_10, 8_0)= -997,
```

Answer (score 3):

I use the following method in my project

```
-(NSArray*)networkErrorCodes
{
    static NSArray *codesArray;
    if (![codesArray count]){
        @synchronized(self){
            const int codes[] = {
                //kCFURLErrorUnknown,     //-998
                //kCFURLErrorCancelled,   //-999
                //kCFURLErrorBadURL,      //-1000
                //kCFURLErrorTimedOut,    //-1001
                //kCFURLErrorUnsupportedURL, //-1002
                //kCFURLErrorCannotFindHost, //-1003
                kCFURLErrorCannotConnectToHost,     //-1004
                kCFURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost,   //-1005
                kCFURLErrorDNSLookupFailed,         //-1006
                //kCFURLErrorHTTPTooManyRedirects,    //-1007
                kCFURLErrorResourceUnavailable,     //-1008
                kCFURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet,  //-1009
                //kCFURLErrorRedirectToNonExistentLocation,   //-1010
                kCFURLErrorBadServerResponse,               //-1011
                //kCFURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication,     //-1012
                //kCFURLErrorUserAuthenticationRequired,      //-1013
                //kCFURLErrorZeroByteResource,        //-1014
                //kCFURLErrorCannotDecodeRawData,     //-1015
                //kCFURLErrorCannotDecodeContentData, //-1016
                //kCFURLErrorCannotParseResponse,     //-1017
                kCFURLErrorInternationalRoamingOff, //-1018
                kCFURLErrorCallIsActive,                //-1019
                //kCFURLErrorDataNotAllowed,              //-1020
                //kCFURLErrorRequestBodyStreamExhausted,  //-1021
                kCFURLErrorFileDoesNotExist,            //-1100
                //kCFURLErrorFileIsDirectory,             //-1101
                kCFURLErrorNoPermissionsToReadFile,     //-1102
                //kCFURLErrorDataLengthExceedsMaximum,     //-1103
            };
            int size = sizeof(codes)/sizeof(int);
            NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            for (int i=0;i<size;++i){
                [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:codes[i]]];
            }
            codesArray = [array copy];
        }
    }
    return codesArray;
}
```

Then I just check the error code and show alert if it is in the list

```
if ([[self networkErrorCodes] containsObject:[NSNumber
numberWithInt:[error code]]]){ 
// Fire Alert View Here
}
```

But as you can see I commented out codes that I think does not fit to my definition of NO INTERNET. E.g the code of -1012 (Authentication fail.)
You may edit the list as you like.

In my project I use it at username/password entering from user. And in my view (physical) network connection errors could be the only reason to show alert view in your network based app. In any other case (e.g. incorrect username/password pair) I prefer to do some custom user friendly animation, OR just repeat the failed attempt again without any attention of the user. Especially if the user didn't explicitly initiated a network call.

Regards to martinezdelariva for a link to documentation.

Comment: That could be a class method!

Answer (score 2):

I found a new error code which is not documented above:
CFNetworkErrorCode -1022

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1022 "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection."
```

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5835
`<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
</dict>`

Answer (score 1):

I found this page in the documentation which has an objective-c enum for all of the error codes under the NSURLErrorDomain.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/URL_Loading_System_Error_Codes

Answer (score 0):

The following site is also very useful for finding undocumented or hard to find Apple API error codes:

https://www.osstatus.com/

You can supply just the error code (such as -1001 or `kCFURLErrorTimedOut`) or even the Framework or API you are using (such as `CFNetwork`, `NSURL` or `AVAudioSession`) and the site will list all potential errors that match your search, showing the error names, relevant Framework and header files in which the error(s) are defined.