# categorise UIWebView errors and display on iphone app?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

is their any category for UIWebView possible errors? in my app i need to display the actual error occurred while loading url. i can print the error in didFailLoadWithError method , but in gives a long description about the error something like

```
didFailLoadWithError Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo=0x895fb10 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://mobilelogin.bwanet.ca/mdninput.html?csphostid=J13y8E9t000Mb3ZK00001H7R, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://mobilelogin.bwanet.ca/mdninput.html?csphostid=J13y8E9t000Mb3ZK00001H7R, NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found., NSUnderlyingError=0x8c68f20 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found."}
```

how will i categorise these possible errors and i want to display it like
"specified hostname could not be found"
"url timeout error"
etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this post you can find list of possible error codes, which will help you to categorize it using your specific error strings: [Undocumented NSURLErrorDomain error codes (-1001, -1003 and -1004) using StoreKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778167/undocumented-nsurlerrordomain-error-codes-1001-1003-and-1004-using-storeki)

Answer (score 0):

okay, in didFailWithError method

```
if (error.code==NSURLErrorTimedOut) {

      errorReason=@"URL Time Out Error ";

   }
    else if (error.code==NSURLErrorCannotFindHost) {
      errorReason=@"Cannot Find Host ";

   }
       else if (error.code==NSURLErrorCannotConnectToHost) {
           errorReason=@"Cannot Connect To Host";

    }
             else if (error.code==NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost) {
               errorReason=@"Network Connection Lost";

       }
                   else if (error.code==NSURLErrorUnknown) {
                        errorReason=@"Unknown Error";

             }
                               else {
                                   errorReason=@"Loading Failed";

                   }
 UIAlertView *errorAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:errorReason message:@"Redirecting to the server failed. do you want to EXIT the app"  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"EXIT" otherButtonTitles:@"RELOAD", nil];


  [errorAlert show];
  [errorAlert release];
```

Comment: you see all those "else if"s? that is why the "switch" statement was invented

Comment: Or better yet enum myEnum { LoadingFaild = -1 } Dictionary<int,string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string> ();;
   dict.Add (-1, "LoadingFailed");

   Console.WriteLine ("Error loading = {0}", dict [-1]);

Comment: or dict[myEnum.LoadingFailed]