# Dropbox ios sdk Download image Error

Tags: iphone, ios, dropbox-api

Hi am developing app that downloads the images from Dropbox. i used latest Dropbox ios sdk, it works fine for less array has less then 5, if array has more than 5 remain will not get download gives error message the error is with 1001 code can not download method. i am using following method

```
for (AppRecord *appRecord in imagesFromDropbox)
        {
            if ([self isValidatedata:appRecord])
            {
                NSString *fileName = [self.utils getFileNameFromPath:appRecord.imageURLString];
                NSString *destPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
                [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
                [[self restClient] loadFile:appRecord.imageURLString intoPath:destPath];
            }
        }
```

any one help. Thanks

Here is the error:

> Error loading metadata: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1001.)" UserInfo=0xa8a03f0 {path=/Photos/Sample Album/2012-04-04 19.52.31.jpg, destinationPath=~/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/06DF2126-6E96-4E4B-A1E1-F6B5C8F8631C/tmp/2012-04-04 19.52.31.jpg}

Comment: What's the complete error?

Comment: this is error :- Error loading metadata: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1001.)" UserInfo=0xa8a03f0 {path=/Photos/Sample Album/2012-04-04 19.52.31.jpg, destinationPath=~/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/06DF2126-6E96-4E4B-A1E1-F6B5C8F8631C/tmp/2012-04-04 19.52.31.jpg}

Comment: The destination path doesn't seem valid. On my computer the `iPhone Simulator` directory is in `~/Library/Application Support`. Does the destination path exist on your computer?

Comment: its just example path the printed path exist on my computer. and it works till 5 images download.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778167/undocumented-nsurlerrordomain-error-codes-1001-1003-and-1004-using-storeki?g_q=nsurlerrordomain%201001

Comment: any one has idea about it.. help me

Comment: @Madhubalan is this fixed anyway?

Comment: No i limited user selection to 5 images at a time