# Data task with URL timed out

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I am trying to access a website. I am using a `dataTaskWithURL` request.

Here is my code:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

    print("2")

    if let urlContent = data {

        print("3")

        let stringContent = NSString(data: urlContent, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

        let arr = stringContent.componentsSeparatedByString("<b>The computer's solutions will appear below</b><br>")

        let second = arr[1]

        let newArr = second.componentsSeparatedByString("</tr></table></center><p align=\"center\">")

        let results = newArr[0]

        self.resultsLabel.text = results

        self.stopActivity()
    } else {
        print(error)
        self.stopActivity()
    }
})

task.resume()
```

I have also tried running this code on the main block:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
    // Code
})
```

However, neither of these has been successful. I repeatedly get the following error

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "**The request timed out.**" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7ff0a3f4c6e0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=*THE URL I AM TRYING TO ACCESS*, NSErrorFailingURLKey=*THE URL I AM TRYING TO ACCESS*, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.})

I have tried looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34581690/nsurlsession-timeout) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23428793/nsurlsession-how-to-increase-time-out-for-url-requests) as well. However, I have not been successful with them. The website loads fairly quickly. How do I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I was using `https://` instead of `http://`.

Answer (score 0):

It could be caused by a number of things; If the issue is happening in the Simulator, I suggest restarting it as per the suggestions in the SO posts below:

- [Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372318/error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1005-the-network-connection-was-lost?lq=1)
- [Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26972822/error-error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1001-the-request-timed-out)
- [NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 error when a http post request is sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27159510/nsurlerrordomain-code-1001-error-when-a-http-post-request-is-sent)
- [Undocumented NSURLErrorDomain error codes (-1001, -1003 and -1004) using StoreKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778167/undocumented-nsurlerrordomain-error-codes-1001-1003-and-1004-using-storeki)
- [How to use NSURLSessionDataTask in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040893/how-to-use-nsurlsessiondatatask-in-swift)

It might be help to print `response` as well to see if the HTTP headers can provide a clue.