# NSURLErrorDomain code=-1005 from GKLeaderboard loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:

Tags: ios, ios8, game-center, nsoperationqueue, nsurlerrordomain

I am receiving the following error in a callback to `loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:`

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1005.)"
```

Other calls to Game Center both before and afterwards succeed. (They operate on various threads). If have initialized the leaderboard request as follows:

```
GKLeaderboard *leaderboard = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] init];

leaderboard.identifier  = leaderboardIdentifier; // valid identifier
leaderboard.playerScope = GKLeaderboardPlayerScopeFriendsOnly;
leaderboard.range       = NSMakeRange(1, 100); // max. allowed range.
leaderboard.timeScope   = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;

[leaderboard loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
    // ...
}];
```

What is going on here and how can I overcome this problem?

The calls to `loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:` are made from an operation on an `NSOperationQueue` whose task it is to issue requests for scores (I am interested in each `localPlayerScore`) to several leaderboards and wait for all responses. The first response already carries the error.

**UPDATE** -1005 denotes [`kCFURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9415479/1789384); the underlying cause is still unclear.

**UPDATE** If I send only a single request (instead of as so far typically 6 in parallel) I receive error `NSURLErrorDomain` -1001, which denotes `kCFURLErrorTimedOut`, or `GKErrorDomain` 3 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason this alternative call does not lead to errors:

```
GKLeaderboard *leaderboard = 
    [[GKLeaderboard alloc] initWithPlayers:@[ GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer ]];

leaderboard.identifier = leaderboardIdentifier;
leaderboard.timeScope  = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;

[leaderboard loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
    // ...
}];
```

Problem solved.