# What the name of the error domain for HTTP error codes?

Tags: ios

I have some network code which behaves differently if an error is due to timeout, bad url, url not found etc, etc. which are all covered by NSURLErrorDomain.

However if I get a http error, such as http 406, then that's not in NSURLErrorDomain. The domain is "HTTP Error", but I don't want to use that as a hardcoded string, I want to use whatever its NSWhateverErrorDomain definition is, but after loads of searching I just can't find what that is anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Undocumented NSURLErrorDomain error codes (-1001, -1003 and -1004) using StoreKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778167/undocumented-nsurlerrordomain-error-codes-1001-1003-and-1004-using-storeki)

Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/cfnetwork/cfnetworkerrors