# Sending a HTTP request in Swift and getting 1001, 999 errors

Tags: swift, xcode, http, info.plist

I have been given the following lines of code, which aim to send a value to an IP in Java. According to my understanding, it seems to be a GET method. But, there is no parameter being sent. Feel free to correct me, as I am fully illiterate in android programming.

```
private class Background_get extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
      /* Change the IP to the IP you set in the arduino sketch */
      URL url = new URL("http://192.168.43.142/?" + params[0]);
      HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
      StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
      String inputLine;
      while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        result.append(inputLine).append("\n");
      in.close();
      connection.disconnect();
      return result.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Receiver of this is an `arduino` and the way it processes sent data is through checking and comparing the last character. For further clarification, please refer to the following lines :

```
  char c = client.read();
        Serial.write(c);
        buffered +=c;
        if(buffered.endsWith("O")){ // this is for TV
           //digitalWrite(pin2,HIGH);
           irsend.sendPanasonic(0x4004,0x100BCBD);    
           delay(100);
         } else if (buffered.endsWith("X")) {
          irsend.sendPanasonic(0x4004,0x1004C4D); 
         } else if (buffered.endsWith("P")) {
          irsend.sendPanasonic(0x4004,0x1000405); 
         } else if (buffered.endsWith("M")) {
          irsend.sendPanasonic(0x4004,0x1008485); 
         } else if (buffered.endsWith("1"))
```

What I have currently done here is first to setup the info.plist for the HTTP communication like so :

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>192.168.43.142</key> 
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

And here I define my IP address :

```
enum API : String {
    case url = "http://192.168.43.142/?"

}
```

and I use it in the following way :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         var httpRequest = API.url.rawValue
        let clicked_btn = indexPath.row
        switch clicked_btn {

        case 0 :

            httpRequest = "\(httpRequest)CP"


        case 1 :
           httpRequest = "\(httpRequest)1"


        case 2 :
            httpRequest = "\(httpRequest)2"

        case 3 :
            httpRequest = "\(httpRequest)3"

        case 4 :
            httpRequest = "\(httpRequest)CM"

        case 5:
           httpRequest = "\(httpRequest)4"

        case 6 :
            httpRequest = "\(httpRequest)5"

        case 7 :
            httpRequest = "\(httpRequest)6"
        case 8 :
            httpRequest = "\(httpRequest)P"

        case 9 :
            httpRequest = "\(httpRequest)7"

        case 10 :
            httpRequest = "\(httpRequest)8"

        case 11:
            httpRequest = "\(httpRequest)9"

        case 12 :
            httpRequest = "\(httpRequest)M"

        case 13 :
            httpRequest = "\(httpRequest)X"
        case 14 :
            httpRequest = "\(httpRequest)0"

        case 15 :
            httpRequest = "\(httpRequest)O"


        default :
            print("deaf")
            break
    }
        //send the HTTP Request :
        print( "my http request is ====> \(httpRequest)")

        let url = URL(string: "\(httpRequest)")!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            //do stuff with data, response, error
            print("Response : \(response)")


        }

        task.resume()

}
```

The problem here is that I keep getting the following error in the console.I have no idea where am I making mistake. I have checked most of the other similar questions but could not figure any answer.

```
 my http request is ====> http://192.168.43.142/?O
    2018-03-02 19:06:43.749016+0800 Master_Project[1687:584006] Task <8BCA1C8B-6571-491D-85D7-97BE6633E720>.<1> finished with error - code: -1001
    2018-03-02 19:06:43.766883+0800 Master_Project[1687:584006] Task <8BCA1C8B-6571-491D-85D7-97BE6633E720>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])
    Response : nil
```

I strongly appreciate your kind help. It's worth mentioning that I have tried this both on simulator and the real device and they both ended up giving me the same error [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code -1001 mean that your connection timed out. Looks like your setup fails to connect to the server. For testing purpose you could make your `NSAppTransportSecurity` settings simpler and just set `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to `true`; if the connection works this way you know it's related to the configuration.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9415479/5471218)'s a list of some network-related error codes.